# How to specify the specific database on the server in cx_oracle.connect

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have to connect to an Oracle server and only use a specific database on the server. I have logon information like this:

```
hostname = 'xxxxx.yyyy.xxxx.net:1521/{server_name}'
user_name= 'user'
password = 'password'
db_name= 'uuuu'
cx_Oracle.connect(user_name, password, hostname)
```

How can specify the db_name in the connect statement in the connect statement?

The above allows me to query: `select * from uuuu.my_table;`. So how can I specify `uuuu` in the connect such that I don't have to add each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"uuuu" in your example appears to be a schema name not a database name.  You cannot specify a schema name in your connection string (other than by logging in as the "uuuu" user).  Once you have connected to the database, however, you can run the statement

```
alter session set current_schema = uuuu;
```

That will cause the statement

```
select * from my_table
```

to look for a `my_table` object in the "uuuu" schema rather than looking for it in the current user's schema.  Alternatively, you can create synonyms (public or private) for `my_table` and the other "uuuu" schema objects you want to reference.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html)...

```
import cx_Oracle

userpwd = ". . ." # Obtain password string from a user prompt or environment variable

connection = cx_Oracle.connect("hr", userpwd, "dbhost.example.com/orclpdb1", encoding="UTF-8")
```

The 'ocrlpdb1' at the end of the connect string, that's the Service name for the database, that is running on dbhost.example.com. We're assuming Oracle Listener on that machine is using port 1521 (the default).

Comment: I can positively confirm that I have both a service_name and a db then. Because running with the posted settings. allows me to query: "select * uuuu.my_table". So how can I specify 'uuuu' in the connect such that I don't have to add each time

Comment: change your connection string to be connect("uuuu", userpwd, ...)